# If $n^{th}$ term of a series $T_n=\frac{n^4}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$, find the sum of first n terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The options are -

$1) \frac{n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)}{18}$

$2)\frac{n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)}{6(2n+1)}$

$3) \frac{n(n^2+n+1)}{3(2n+1)}$

$4) \frac{n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n}{3(2n+1)}$

$5) \frac{n(n+1)(2n^2+n+1)}{2(2n+1)}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{n^4}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\dfrac{n^2}4+\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac1{16}\cdot\dfrac1{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$

$$\dfrac2{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\dfrac{2n+1-(2n-1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=f(n)-f(n-1)$$ where $f(m)=\dfrac1{2m+1}$

Answer (score 1):

That's kinda cheeating, but if you have potential candidates for $S_n \sum_{k=1}^n T_n$, you can calculate $S_n- S_{n-1}$ and check which one is equal to $T_n$. Then you oly need to check whether $S_1=T_1$, and then from the induction it follows that the chosen formula for $S_n$ is be correct.

Comment: I'm  supposed to solve this question in 4 mins. This way it would require a lot of time.